# Select each element that match another one to make a dynamic side nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to make a dynamic list that can change the active element on the div scroll.
For that, I have a navigation list like this

```
<div class="liste-categorie">
    <ul id="top-menu">
        <li><a class="hover-3" href="#sashimis">Sashimis</a></li>
        <li><a class="hover-3" href="#Californiarolls">Californiarolls</a></li>
        <li><a class="hover-3" href="#Rainbowrolls">Rainbowrolls</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the targeted content

```
<div class="col-md-9 wow zoomIn articles">
    <div class="container-fluid items">
        <div id="Sashimis" class="item"></div>
        <div id="Californiarolls" class="item"></div>
        <div id="Rainbowrolls" class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So where is my script for the scroll

```
$(".articles").scroll(function() {
    var windscroll = $(".articles").scrollTop();
    if (windscroll >= 0) {
        $('.items .item').each(function(i,obj) {
            if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll && $(this).position().top + $(this).height() > windscroll) {
                $('#top-menu li.activate').removeClass('activate');
                $('#top-menu li').eq(i).addClass('activate');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#top-menu li.activate').removeClass('activate');
        $('#top-menu li').addClass('activate');
    }
}).scroll();
```

But it's not working. What did I do wrong ? ;_;

Comment: Just FYI bootstrap has a component which can do this for you: [ScrollSpy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)

Comment: Also please click `<>` to add a [mcve]